# Is there any practical difference between Append(Environment.NewLine) and AppendLine(string.empty), or is it just a stylistic choice?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Presumably, all of these lines have the same effect:

```
stringyBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
stringyBuilder.AppendLine(string.Empty);
stringyBuilder.AppendLine();
```

(stringyBuilder is, if not obvious, a StringBuilder object).

...so is one to be preferred over the others, or is it a matter of religious zeal?

Comment: You are aware of the third option, `AppendLine()`?

Comment: Now I am; I will update.

Comment: Just a stylistic choice.

Comment: Well, the last one is both shorter and has less stuff to parse.

Comment: Don't forget `stringyBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}", Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: It's always good to check the Reference Source. `stringyBuilder.AppendLine()` is just a shortcut for `stringyBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine)`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs#c0554798fe05ba4f

Comment: So .AppendLine(Environment.NewLine) is the shortest way to add two, count 'em, two, lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all functionally equivalent.  `stringyBuilder.AppendLine(string.Empty);` would add one call to `Append` which would cause some extra processing:

From [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs#73bc75596acbac77)

```
public StringBuilder AppendLine() {
    return Append(Environment.NewLine);
}

public StringBuilder AppendLine(string value) {
    Append(value);
    return Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Documentation of `StringBuilder.AppendLine()`

> Appends the default line terminator to the end of the current StringBuilder object.

If you're asking about preferences, I think `stringyBuilder.AppendLine();` would be preferred by most because it's shorter and has zero performance impact versus `stringyBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);`

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the first and the third options, because `AppendLine` is [implemented](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Text/StringBuilder.cs) as a call of `Append` which passes `System.Environment.NewLine`:

```
public StringBuilder AppendLine () {
    return Append (System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

The middle option is sub-optimal, because it tries to append an empty string. This takes very little time, though, and it is functionally equivalent to the other two.